# I have game Catan 3061 and want to buy an extension, are extensions 3066 and 3078 the same?

Tags: catan-cities-and-knights

https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/item/344333090392539/?ref=search&referral_code=marketplace_search&referral_story_type=post&tracking=browse_serp%3Add6711d2-6b1a-4fe2-bd24-1828b21608e8

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07B8WZJGX/ref=ox_sc_saved_image_3?smid=&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07B8WZJGX)

I have game 3061 and want to buy an extension, are extensions 3066 and 3078 the same?

Comment: Catan game 3061

Answer (score 1):

*Catan* 3061 is typically referred to as **4th Edition**, and while *Catan: Cities and Knights* 3066 is officially called **2nd Edition**, it is designed to work with *Catan* 3061.

While *C&K* 3078 has been updated for *Catan* **5th Edition** it will work with 3061, but the art will be different from your base game.